# Create new dictionary from another but keeping the same key

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, nlp, tags

I want to create a dictonnary from another one but with keeping the same key. I tried to update the value of my first dictionary but I got the error. So now I am trying to create a new dictionary from the first one.

I would like the key to be the same and not change them.

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import codecs 
import re
import os
import sys, argparse
import subprocess
import pprint
import csv
from itertools import islice
import pickle

try:
    import treetaggerwrapper
    from treetaggerwrapper import TreeTagger, make_tags
    print("import TreeTagger OK")
except:
    print("Import TreeTagger pas Ok")

from itertools import islice
from collections import defaultdict



#export le lexique de sentiments
pickle_in = open("dict_pickle", "rb")
dico_lexique = pickle.load(pickle_in)


# extraction colonne verbatim
d = {}
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r', encoding="cp1252",) as csv_file:
    csv_file.readline()
    for line in csv_file:
        token = line.split(';')
        d[token[0]] = token[1]
#print(d)

#Writing in a new csv file 

with open('result.csv','wb', sep=';', encoding='Cp1252') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f)
    w.writerows(d.items())

tagger = treetaggerwrapper.TreeTagger(TAGLANG='fr')

d_tag = {}
for key,val in d.items():
    newvalues = tagger.tag_text(val)
    #print(newvalues)
    for key,val in d_tag.items():
        d_tag[key] = d[key]
        d_tag[val] = newvalues
print(d_tag)


#Writing in a new csv file, Writing the key to be sure it coincides

with open('result.csv','wb', sep=';', encoding='Cp1252') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f)
    w.writerows(d_tag.items())
```

file  (this is an example , the original has approx. 6000 lines in the csv

```
id;Verbatim;score
1;tu es laid;5
2;Je suis belle; 6
3;Je n'aime pas la viande;7
```

What it looks after extracting the first and second column :

```
{'1': 'tu es laid\n', '2': 'Je suis belle \n', '3': "Je n'aime pas la viande"}
```

Expected answer , I would like the tag to correspond to the key of their original sentence

```
d_tag = { "1" : ['tu\tPRO:PER\ttu', 'es\tVER:pres\têtre', 'laid\tADJ\tlaid'],
"2" : ['Je\tPRO:PER\tje', 'suis\tVER:pres\tsuivre|être', 'belle\tADJ\tbeau'],
"3" : ['Je\tPRO:PER\tje', "n'\tADV\tne", 'aime\tVER:pres\taimer', 'pas\tADV\tpas', 'la\tDET:ART\tle', 'viande\tNOM\tviande']}
```

Later, I would like to extract only the third word (looping over the second dictionary and rewriting a new one with the same key but containing only the lemma which are at the index[2].

That means obtaining something like this :

```
d_lemma = { "1" : ['tu', 'être', 'laid'],
"2" : ['Je', 'suivre|être', 'beau'],
"3" : ['Je', "ne", 'aimer', 'pas', 'le', 'viande']}
```

the code above is not working , any idea how to change it,  to get the result I am expecting for the second dictionary.

Unfortunately, I have to use the key to preserve the sentences so that I will be able to write the values  one by one in the csv  either at each step or at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To map the new tag values to the related key, make the key the key and the new value the value:

```
d_tag = {}
for key, val in d.items():
    newvalues = tagger.tag_text(val)
    d_tag[key] = newvalues
```

This code can be shortened by using a dictionary comprehension:

```
d_tag = {key: tagger.tag_text(val) for key, val in d.items()}
```

To get the lemma dictionary, you need to call `str.split` on each element in each value list, then extract the third item in each result and add it to the list of values for the associated key.

```
d_lemma = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in d_tag.items():
    for elem in v:
        parts = elem.split('\t')
        d_lemma[k].append(parts[2])
```

Result:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'1': ['tu', 'être', 'laid'], '2': ['je', 'suivre|être', 'beau'], '3': ['je', 'ne', 'aimer', 'pas', 'le', 'viande']})
```

Again, the code can be shortened using a dictionary comprehension, with an inner list comprehension to create the value:

```
d_lemma = {k: [p.split('\t')[2] for p in v] for k, v in d_tag.items()}
```

Result:

```
{'1': ['tu', 'être', 'laid'], '2': ['je', 'suivre|être', 'beau'], '3': ['je', 'ne', 'aimer', 'pas', 'le', 'viande']}
```

Comment: thank you iti is working for my small example, unfortunately when i tired for the real csv file which have 5423 lines per column[1], it says :  list index out of range  , do you know how can i solve it ?

Comment: File "CSV_2.py", line 33, in <module>
    d[token[0]] = token[1]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @kely789456123 that error happens because you have a line in the file that does contain enough parts when split by the delimiter `';'`.  You _could_ test that `len(token) > 0` before adding to `d`.  However a likely cause is that the original csv has a blank line at the end.  Processing the file with `csv.reader` instead of iterating manually should handle this case automatically.